# Creating word cloud in Python from column in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud from a column in a csv file using python. I've installed wordcloud, PIL, OS, and Numpy but I'm not sure how to read in just that one column to create the word cloud. Is anyone able to assist? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please clarify your question, show what you've tried already and what output/errors you are getting and we can try to help

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 5):

Here is modified example from [word_cloud site](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud).

I had a `'words.csv` file with words (which are selected and shown in image below) in first column and their explanation in next.

We read first column on `csv` file (words) and then run through `word_cloud`.

```
import csv
from wordcloud import WordCloud


#read first column of csv file to string of words seperated
#by tab

your_list = []
with open('words.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = '\t'.join([i[0] for i in reader])


# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(your_list)

# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")

# lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(your_list)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

# The pil way (if you don't have matplotlib)
# image = wordcloud.to_image()
# image.show()
```

**Image**
[image]